# High Current DC Motor Driver

Tags: motor, dc

I have seen this [datasheet](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2eQHI-8lNVxY2w4SDZGdWNaTzg/edit?usp=sharing) of high current DC motor Driver. Its mentioned that it can be used to drive the motor in forward or reverse direction. I puzzled by seeing only 2 X IR7843 MOSFET's are being used can any one help me to understand how it works.

Comment: Parts on the back-side of the board?

Comment: Can you provide a link for IR7843 - International rectifier doesn't seem to recognize this part.

Comment: @Andyaka www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irlr7843.pdf‎

Comment: is that IRF7843 ? or irlr7843 ? http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irlr7843pbf.pdf

Comment: @sandundhammika may be, but i need to know the concept

Answer (score 7):

I emailed Robokits India with the following question:

> In looking at the Users Manual for the RKI-1340, the specifications indicate forward and reverse motion may be achieved. This would imply that an H-bridge circuit is used, but the image of the board only shows 2 power mosfets (an H-bridge requires 4). Is this an image of the actual board? Are there additional power mosfets on the back side of the board? Can you please share a schematic?

and received the following response:

> 2 power mosfets are on the bottom side of the board.

From the [RKI-1340 Users Manual](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2eQHI-8lNVxY2w4SDZGdWNaTzg/edit?usp=sharing) under "Connector Information":

> V(+) 24Vmax and GND(-): Power Supply input to driver (Input Voltage)

This pretty much rules out the use of a dual-polarity power-supply.

I believe there can be very little doubt, the circuit is indeed an H-bridge.

**Update:**
I decided to email them (Robokits India) one more time for clairification:

> Is there a schematic and/or service manual available? Can you confirm that the design is an H-bridge?

Again no schematic (or explicit refusal), but they did confirm that it is an H-bridge:

> The design is a H-bridge driver only but you cannot use half bridge configuration on the same. The input signal will drive all four mosfets at once. There are no separate inputs for half bridges.

Comment: did you get schematic

Comment: No, the quote above was their entire response.

Comment: @yogece Were you looking for an explanation of how an H-bridge works, or possibly on how the control inputs to the board are used, or was this what you were looking for?

Comment: i am looking for a MOSFET based H-Bridge capable of driving 20A DC motor(with discrete component based MOSFET driver)

Comment: According to their specs and their confirmations above, this board should meet those requirements.

Comment: but i need schematic

Answer (score 3):

There are several possible answers of this question:

1. As Tut already said - there are two more MOSFETS at the back of the board.
2. The photo in the .PDF is not for the actual device, but for similar looking driver that can control only the speed of the motor, but not the direction.
3. Actually there **exists a way** to control the speed and the direction by only two MOSFETS - use two power sources with common ground. But this is not very likely in this case.

Comment: yes it is possible to control the direction by using two MOSFETs but we should use dual polarity power supply +- 12V

Comment: @yogece - that was my point as well.